# Simple mysqli query not returning anything

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am almost certain that this is a boneheaded question with a very simple answer, but I've been knocking my brain against the desk for the last 30 minutes or so and figured it was time to ask for help.

I need to fetch the current highest existing keyID in the database. Simple! So I did this:

```
$newIDQ = "SELECT MAX(mediaKey) FROM `imd_media`";
$newIDResult = $con->query($newIDQ);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($newIDResult);
echo "Highest ID should be: " . $row['mediaKey'];
```

But it never spits anything out in $row['mediaKey']. It's been awhile since I used mySQL for anything and this is my first tussle with mysqli, so I'm sure I'm just looking right past the answer or misunderstanding something.

Comment: You should add error handling to all database operations. And do you have a database connection open?

Comment: `var_dump($row)` would show you exactly what you should be using.

Comment: so? was you question answered?

Answer (score 3):

`$row[0]` will do it I believe.

Always debug your code. Say, for your current problem `print_r($row);` can help

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$newIDQ = "SELECT MAX(mediaKey) AS mediaKey FROM `imd_media`"; // rename the result col
$newIDResult = $con->query($newIDQ);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($newIDResult);
echo "Highest ID should be: " . $row['mediaKey'];
```

or this:

```
$newIDQ = "SELECT MAX(mediaKey) FROM `imd_media`";
$newIDResult = $con->query($newIDQ);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($newIDResult);
echo "Highest ID should be: " . $row['MAX(mediaKey)']; // your probable current result
```

Comment: What did you change? Why do you think it will work? what is your query doing differently from the OPS?

Comment: @Daryl Gill: I renamed the col with the AS... because the result column will be 'MAX(mediakey)'

Comment: You should include your changes and why you think it should work in your answers

Comment: @Daryl Gill: It is self explanatory... I don't think that that should be cause for a -1... less with all the answers I see around this site... He seems to know enough of mysql to see my change in this 4 lines

Comment: My -1 is now locked in; I cannot change.

Comment: Calm down @Manatax, now you are just showing off. Daryl didn't mean it (LOL)

Comment: Lol... I just don't appreciate the fast -1ers ... I guess is something I got from the time I was asking the questions... :P I know Daryl means well...

Answer (score 0):

```
$newIDQ = "SELECT MAX(mediaKey) FROM 'imd_media'";

$newIDResult = $con->query($newIDQ);

$row = $newIDResult ->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo "Highest ID should be: " . $row['mediaKey'];`
```

Comment: I have to do this again? ---
What did you change? Why do you think it will work? what is your query doing differently from the OPS?

Comment: @Mikaele please read up on how to format your post. things need to be formated well so others can understand.

Comment: @Daryl Gill **MYSQLI_ASSOC**

Comment: Could you put some description with the answer.